# Display svg with semantic-ui-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, semantic-ui-react

How do I display images with semantic-ui-react Image component?
I notice that the non react version says it supports svg and `img` but the react version does not state whether it does or not.
What I'm doing is

```
<Image src={ImagePath}/>
```

However, I just see a broken image icon.
Webpack compiles it correctly so the path is not wrong.
Can someone let me know what the best solution to my problem is?

Comment: You may need the image webpack loader at "https://www.npmjs.com/package/image-webpack-loader", and then you may need to modify your webpack.config.js to allow images.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using webpack4 and following are the settings I use for images,

> webpack.config.js, module rules -

```
{
    test: /\.(ttf|woff|woff2|eot|png|svg|gif)$/,
    use: {
    loader: 'url-loader',
    options: {
            limit: 10000
        }
    }
}
```

I've a  `static/`  directory  inside  `src/`  containing images and using  `CopyWebpackPlugin` , I copy all these images in  `build/`  as,

> webpack.config.js, module plugins -

```
new CopyWebpackPlugin([ { from: 'src/static' } ]),
```

> Finally to use the **svg** in Image component of semantic-ui-react, I refer it by relative path as -

```
<Image src="/images/logo.svg" alt="no logo"/>
```

Hope this helps.